# Configure proxy for list of domains

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

I want to configure proxy (Sock5 with login/pass) to some domains, like *.askubuntu.*.
I can do it in firefox with extension Foxyproxy, but in chrome is doesn't work (socks5 proxy with auth don't work in chrome)
Can I somehow configure this for whole system?
I try to find proxyclient with GUI, but I can't find anything.